# How to convert a single year to type NumPy datetime

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, time, python-xarray

I need to overcome a mapping related error `TypeError: input must have type NumPy datetime`. I have time axis with following attributes and I only have single year data.

```
In [26]: times[t]


Out [26]: xarray.DataArray 'time'

    array(1992.)

    Coordinates:
        time        ()        float64        1.992e+03

    Attributes:

    standard_name :     time
    units :             year as %Y.%f
    calendar :          proleptic_gregorian
    axis :              T
```

How can I convert into Numpy datatime?

I tried the following, but didn't work.

```
np.datetime_as_string(times[t],timezone='UTC')
```

Any help/advice is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can work with the [datetime accessor in xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.accessor_dt.DatetimeAccessor.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like pandas, numpy has also a datetime method called numpy.datetime64() to work with date and time.

For example to convert a year into a numpy datetime:

np.datetime64("1992")

numpy.datetime64('1992')

Detailed information about the datetime in numpy can be found in the following documentation.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Teklehaimanot Thank you for your suggestion. It lead me to the solution of my problem.